# GROUP BY using 2 columns - Is this actually possible?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a summary sheet which looks at PO Numbers, Site and the sum of all rows containing that PO

1 Site can have many POs and 1 PO can have many rows for a sum total

[image]

I tried this it include additional columns which will be the same details against multiple POs such as contractor, dates etc

[image]

I know it's wrong but I'm not certain why

Am I trying to group incompatible field combinations or is there a greater level of misunderstanding I have here?

Apologies, I tried to post the code and an example but it wouldn't accept it

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select statement:

- includes both `Col6` and `sum(Col6)` - which is a contradiction in terms.
- doesn't have an `order by` so that Col1 sorts H above G - or you could order by Col2.

---

Try this:

`=query({A2:G7},"select Col1, Col7, sum(Col6) group by Col7, Col1 order by Col1 desc label Col1 ' ', Col7 ' ',sum(Col6) ' ' format sum(Col6) '$#,##0'")`